# Embed outlook invite into email

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to use a calendar scheduling functionality within an email invite to an event. Is there a way of embedding this into an email so people could click through from the email and add the date automatically into their diaries on Outlook or gmail?

HTML or Javascript prefered, and if it a simple yes or no that is perfect!

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't. A lack of standards and interoperability between calendar apps prevents this.

Comment: You're right - Although what I have done as a workaround is if you create an event in Outlook it creates a file .ics and if you attach that to an email it is supported by many clients and for example Gmail will add it to your gmail calendar.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_applications_with_iCalendar_support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way - but you can host the iCalendar invite in a link.